# How can I perform line change for "~~~" in MS Word?

Tags: microsoft-word

I have some sentences like

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. "Sed neque libero, pretium ac elit non, condimentum ullamcorper eros"Sed semper luctus dui. Duis mollis congue urna.
```

Or

```
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit"Sed neque libero, pretium ac elit non, condimentum ullamcorper eros.
```

or

```
Lorem ipsum dolor"sit amet, consectetur"adipiscing elit.
```

I wish to make them like

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
"Sed neque libero, pretium ac elit non, condimentum ullamcorper eros"
Sed semper luctus dui. Duis mollis congue urna.
```

or

```
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit"
Sed neque libero, pretium ac elit non, condimentum ullamcorper eros.
```

or

```
Lorem ipsum dolor 
"sit amet, consectetur" 
adipiscing elit.
```

for the entire text of the file. But I'm not sure are there any good strategies for this line change for "~~~" contents using find and replace, or any other method.

Problem is, there are lots of parts, where no space or no dots before or after "". This makes it hard to use find and replace option for this work...

Comment: Because they can have variations, quite sure find and replace with each variation might be the only way to switch any variation with multiple at once. Any way its done, must deal with variations. To do it fast there must be no variations. Computers don't deal well with differences but need 2+2 to be 4 unless someone makes 2+2 be something else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The title, with "~~~", is unclear. I think what you want to do is find strings of quoted text and place each one in its own paragraph, separate from what might be before it or after it. A regular search and replace is not up to handling the task. Regular expressions, however, can do the job in a snap. While it is not nearly as good (powerful) as what most are used to, Microsoft does have a complex system of wildcard expressions that look like, sort of, regular expressions. Your objective is easily within the power of that system.

On the Word ribbon, click on <kbd>Find</kbd> and select <kbd>Advanced Find...</kbd>. In the dialog box click on the <kbd>More</kbd> button which makes the dialog box larger, with more options. Check the box for "**Use wildcards**". This will allow you to use Microsoft's version of regular expressions.

In this case you want a double quote followed by anything that is not a double quote and then another double quote. The tricky part is the text between the quotes. the symbols `[` and `]` form a group of characters to match, but it only matches one character. We could use a range like `[A-Za-z]` for all capital and lowercase letters, but there could be other characters, such as numbers and commas as well. Instead we can use the **not** symbol `!` and the double quote to match any character that is not a double quote. Like this, `[!"]`.

That will match any *one* character, like the `?` wildcard does, which is not a double quote. To make it match more we use the count control `{` and `}`. It can either be used to indicate how many to match, `{4}` match four characters, or set a range `{3,10}` match at least three, and as many as possible up to ten. If the maximum is left off the range it acts like the `*` and matches as many as it can, `{5,}` match five or more. For this case we need to match at least one, and as many as we can, so it is `{1,}`

Put all together, the pattern we want is `"[!"]{1,}"`. The last part is to make it so that we can use what was found in the search as part of the replacement text. To do that we add `(` and `)` around what we want to keep, like `("[!"]{1,}")` and then we can use it in the replacement part as `\1`, meaning 'the first group found in the search pattern.' There can be more groups, but we don't need them for now.

The final point is that in Word for search and replace the paragraph symbol `¶` cannot be used, but they give you `^p` as a replacement in the 'Replace with' box. That is the carat <kbd>^</kbd> (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd>) and a small letter <kbd>p</kbd>. In the 'Find what' box you have to use the numeric equivalent, which is `^13`.

Next is a decision point for you. Some of the quoted text can be at the beginning of the paragraph, the end of the paragraph, or inside the paragraph. If you don't mind looking for extra lines later you can do it all at once by using

- Find what: `("[!"]{1,}")`
- Replace with: `^p\1^p`

On the other hand, if you want to avoid the work of removing extra blank lines, and are willing to use multiple (3) replacement commands, you can search for each of the possibilities with the appropriate replacements.

At the beginning of the paragraph:

- Find what: `^13("[!"]{1,}")([!^13])`
- Replace with: `^p\1^p\2`

At the end of the paragraph:

- Find what: `([!^13])("[!"]{1,}")^13`
- Replace with: `\1^p\2^p`

Inside the paragraph:

- Find what: `([!^13])("[!"]{1,}")([!^13])`
- Replace with: `\1^p\2^p\3`

On other possibility, if you know that you do not have any blank paragraphs, is to use the first option and then find and remove the extra blank paragraphs:

- Find what: `^13{2}`
- Replace with: `^p`

As a note, I used paragraphs for all the work, but it is possible that you intend to use a manual return, or new line, between the quoted and unquoted sections of text. In that case, where you want to add a new line use `^l` (small letter ell) rather than `^p` in the 'Replace with' box, and if you need to find a new line, use `^11` (eleven) in the 'Find what' box.

If you want to know more about the power of wildcard searches in Word, you can see the Microsoft MVP's page [Finding and replacing characters using wildcards](https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/General/UsingWildcards.htm).

### Control Codes that may be used with the search/replace tool

```
Code    Notes
-----   -------
^1      In-line picture
^2      Auto referenced footnotes
^5      Annotation mark
^9      Tab
^11     New line
^12     Page or Section break
^13     Paragraph break / 'carriage' return
^14     Column break
^19     Opening field brace (when field braces are visible)
^21     Closing field brace (when field braces are visible)
?       Question mark
^?      Any single character (not valid in the Replace box)
^-      Optional hyphen
^~      Non-breaking hyphen
^^      Caret character
^#      Any digit
^$      Any letter
^&      Contents of 'Find What' box (Replace box only)
^+      Em dash  (not valid in the Replace box)
^=      En dash  (not valid in the Replace box)
^u8195  Em Space Unicode character value search (not valid in the Replace box)
^u8194  En Space Unicode character value search (not valid in the Replace box)
^a      Comment (not valid in the replace box)
^b      Section break (not valid in the replace box)
^c      Replace with Clipboard contents (Replace box only)
^d      Field
^e      Endnote Mark (not valid in the Replace box)
^f      Footnote Mark (not valid in the Replace box)
^g      Graphic (In Line Graphics Only). In Word 2007 a forward slash /
        also appears to find in-line graphics. This appears to be an 
        unintentional bug.
^l      New line -
^m      Manual Page Break
^n      Column break
^t      Tab -
^p      Paragraph Mark -
^s      Non-breaking space
^w      White space (space, non-breaking space, tab); not valid in 
        the Replace box
^nnn    Where "n" is an ASCII character number

        Note: ASCII codes below 128 were standardized a long time ago, 
        before the introduction of Windows operating systems. The upper
        codes were used for OS-specific, localized, or vendor-specific 
        stuff. When DOS code pages were replaced by Windows code pages,
        a leading zero was used to indicated the difference.
        Thus ^32 and ^032 will both represent a space character, but
        ^147 will represent ô and ^0147 will represent “
^0nnn   See above (Produces ASCII on Macintosh).
^unnnn  Unicode character search where "n" is a decimal number corresponding
        to the Unicode character value.

Note:   To search for a specific field, such as an XE (Index Entry) field, 
        use the following syntax:
        ^19 field name
```

Comment: If that doesn't cover it, nothing will! Great answer.

Comment: @spikey_richie It would really be nice if MS would add real RegEx to Word/Office. They have it in other products, so it's not a foreign concept to them.

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer and all comments